Remove thin top and bottom margins of caption on minipage
I want to place a caption inside a minipage which is placed inside a tight fbox:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt}%
\fbox{The text here is in a tight box!}\\
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
\caption{Testcaption very long Testcaption very long Testcaption very long Testcaption very long}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}

The result looks like this (please ignore that this says "Figure 3" instead of "Figure 1"):

That is, there is a very small top and bottom margin (1mm at most) inside the box containing the caption. I want to remove this. Which spacing is responsible for this?

There is an option to disable the strut:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt,strut=false}%
\fbox{The text here is in a tight box!}\\
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
\caption{Testcaption very long Testcaption very long Testcaption very long Testcaption very long}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}


